# How to pass a reference of the current DOM element to ng-class

Tags: angularjs

How can we pass a reference to the current DOM element while using ng-class.Do we have something similar to the `$event` object that can be passed to the `ng-click` function to access the target.

My scenario is to know the offset of the current element to determine its class.
I have a vertically scrollable table which will show 8 rows in the view the first 4 rows in the view would have a specific class and the rest 4 will have another class.so i kinda see the offset of the element to determine element is in the first half or the second half.

Comment: you need $index and not offset

Comment: @entre i am not trying to assign the class based on the position of the record in the table but position of the record in the visible window of the table

Comment: $index given you position based on visibility and not for the entire table content

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ng-repeat to iterate the rows, you can use the internal $index variable. ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat))

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-class="{'firstClass: $index < rows.length / 2, 'secondClass': $index >= rows.length / 2}">
```

Comment: rows.length would take both the visible and the not viewable rows in to picture .I am talking about a table which can be scrolled and need to assign class to any 8 set of rows which is in the visible window of the table.